# Using Tesseract ocr in C# Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, ocr, tesseract

I have downloaded `tesseract` from [Here](http://code.google.com/p/tesseractdotnet/downloads/detail?name=TesseractEngine3DotNetWrapper_RC2%20_r552.zip). When i tried to add the `dll` file to visual studio 2012, its showing error that its not an valid assembly. Can anyone suggest me some other `dll` file of `ocr` and sample coding. I've tried many websites but i dint found any good one.  Then i found this `dll` file [tessrect](http://tmp.m4f.eu/tessnet2.zip) and used the following code

```
string path = @"C:\pic\mytext.jpg";
Bitmap image = new Bitmap(path);
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "0123456789"); // If digit only
ocr.Init(@"C:\tessdata\", "eng", false); // To use correct tessdata
List<tessnet2.Word> result = ocr.DoOCR(image, Rectangle.Empty);
foreach (tessnet2.Word word in result)
Console.WriteLine("{0} : {1}", word.Confidence, word.Text);
```

But visual studio throwing error that its not valid assembly. can anyone help me in this ...

EDIT : Frameworks in properties folder only
 Thanks n advance

Comment: Is your target framework in the project properties still on client profile?

Comment: You might try to build in x86 or x64

Answer (score 2):

I tried to use [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). It has more pleasent syntax:

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(pathToLangFolder, "eng", EngineMode.Default))
{
    // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
    using (var image = new Bitmap(fileName))
    {
        using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence() + " : " + page.GetText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why Dont u Try for 
[OCRSDK](http://ocrsdk.com) its an paid service and also available for trial . It as accuracy of 85% in extracting text from image ...

Comment: `private void B8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string ts = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract.exe";
            m = Clipboard.GetImage();
            string rd = ", " + m + v + ", 'eng'";
            if (m != null)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(ts, rd);
                tb5.AppendText(v + Environment.NewLine);
                Clipboard.Clear();
                m = null;
                v = null;
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No Image.");
            }`